# HTTP Request Error With onchange JS Function

Tags: javascript, laravel, forms, post, csrf

I am trying to add a state feature to a ticketing system built in Laravel that will maintain if a ticket is open, closed, on-hold, etc.

I have the states table created, and I can reference that table in my view.

The view has a drop-down menu with all the possible states, and I would like to update the ticket's state when a new state is selected from the drop-down menu.

Currently, I have an onchange JavaScript function running, but I am having an issue submitting the POST request from the JavaScript function. When redirecting to the POST route, I receive the error:
[MethodNotAllowedHttpException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW54d.jpg).

The post route works correctly if I make each state its own form button.

The last time I received this error was because I forgot to pass the CSRF token into a form. However, I have no idea how to do this with a JavaScript function.

I'm sure there is a way to accomplish what I am trying to do, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks for any help!

---

This is my View

```html
<form name="stateForm" action="{{ url($claim->path() . '/state') }}">
    <select id="stateList" onchange="stateChange(this.form)">
            @foreach($states as $state)
                <option id="{{ url($claim->path() . '/state/' . $state->id) }}" value="{{ $state->id }}">{{ $state->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
    </select>
</form>
```

JavaScript called on change

```js
function stateChange(stateForm, URL)
{
    var selIndex = stateForm.stateList.selectedIndex;
    var URL = stateForm.stateList.options[selIndex].id;
    window.location.href = URL;
}
```

Laravel route

```
Route::post('/claims/{claim}/state/{stateID}', 'ClaimController@updateState');
```

Working code using forms and buttons

```html
<div class="btn-group">
@foreach( $states as $state)
    <form method="post" action="{{ url($claim->path() . '/state/'. $state->id) }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button>
            {{ $state->name }}
        </button>
    </form>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.location.href = URL;
```

is a get request that basically redirects

You need to change your route to a GET request instead

```
Route::get('/claims/{claim}/state/{stateID}', 'ClaimController@updateState');
```

Comment: This fixed my issue, but I have a follow-up question.
I thought since I was setting data in my DB, I would need to use a POST. I understand this JS function uses a GET, but why can I then set data with it?

Comment: @dwellerexe - What he means is that when you use that particular line of Javascript, it actually reloads the page (causing a GET). Try it out in the chrome inspector. Type this line `window.location.href = 'https://google.com'` and you will see. Also, depending on how your route works, you could be setting data with a GET but you should probably not do that. Nothing will stop you from making changes to data on a GET, its just generally not good practice / doesn't work with REST standards.